# Problem with movement on JavaScript.. Don't work ArrowUp

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code...I had create a Snake for my website..
In this code dont work the **ArrowUp** in move function...
Help me pls. (;
P.s: (All other movement (left down right) work so well)

```
const snake = [
    {
        x: 15,
        y: 30
    }
];

const key = [
    "ArrowUp ",
    "ArrowRight",
    "ArrowDown",
    "ArrowLeft"
];

let direction = null;
let interval = null;

function run(){
    const playboard = document.getElementById("playboard");

    for (let x = 0; x < config.x; x ++){
        for (let y = 0;y < config.y; y ++){
            const cell = document.createElement("div");
            cell.setAttribute("id",`${x}_${y}`);
            cell.setAttribute("class","cell");

            if (y === 59){
                cell.setAttribute("class","clearLeft");
            }
            playboard.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

    draw();

    window.addEventListener("keydown", event =>{
        if (key.indexOf(event.code) > -1){
            direction = event.code;
        }
    });

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        move();
        draw();
    }, 500)
}

function move() {
    switch(direction) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
        snake[0].y -= 1
        break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
        snake[0].y += 1
        break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
        snake[0].x -= 1
        break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
        snake[0].x += 1
        break;
    default:
        // TODO: Play a fart sound.
        break;
    }
}

function draw(){

    for (let x = 0; x < config.x; x ++){
        for (let y = 0;y < config.y; y ++){
            document.getElementById(`${x}_${y}`).style.backgroundColor = "black";

        }
    }

    snake.forEach(p => {
        document.getElementById(`${p.x}_${p.y}`).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    })

}

const config = {
    x: 30,
    y: 60
};

run(config);
```

Comment: You have a space in your `"ArrowUp "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the space after your ArrowUp in your key. This should fix it

```
const key = [
    "ArrowUp",
    "ArrowRight",
    "ArrowDown",
    "ArrowLeft"
];
```

Comment: Oh thank you  ahhaha. Now all word ahhahah. my fault;)